# In Postman, how to choose a specific example to show as endpoint response in mock server?

Tags: postman

**In brief**

In Postman, at mock server, and at a specific request with multiple saved example, how to pick up an example in the middle of the example list instead of the first one?

**Full details**

Let's say we have an api endpoint `GET /users` and it has three examples saved e1, e2, e3 - listed in that order ie `e1` on top in the example list.

And we create the mock server, called `M`, for the collection in Postman.

Currently when calling this endpoint thru this mock server `M`, we will get mocked response as `e1`.

My question is how can we specify `e2` instead as mocked value?

Comment: Rearrange the examples?

Comment: @matt How to rearrange the examples?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 3 different ways, all documented here - https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/mock-with-api/

TLDR; you can send one of the following 3 headers along with your request:

1. `x-mock-response-code`, if each of the three example responses has a different response code, you can specify the desired response code as the value of this header.
2. `x-mock-response-name`, you can specify the name of the desired example.
3. `x-mock-response-id`, you can specify the uid of the desired example (`<user-id>-<response-id>`)

Comment: `x-mock-response-name` is the name of the example file.